# Why am I getting undefined when asking for json.length?

Tags: json

I have a json like this:

```
{"result":{"sandbox":1,"0":{"id":1106,"url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/index1.html"},"1":{"id":9655,"url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/index2.html"},"2":{"id":8447,"url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/index3.html"}}}
```

and I'm retrieving it and then doing this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(json.length);
```

but the console outputs "undefined" even if when I just log (json) it shows me the object. Why? and how can I get the length? I need it for a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json is not an array so you will not get the length.

If the json has something like [1,2,3] then it is an array

You can get the `console.log(json.result)`

try using the [Online Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Answer (score 0):

The root-level element in that JSON document is an object, not an array. An object has no length property. Instead, you can just print out the whole object:

```
console.log(json);
```

Note that you should really be using arrays instead of numeric keys for an object, like this:

```
{"result":
  {"sandbox":1,
   "results": [
      {"id":1106,"url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/index1.html"},
      {"id":9655,"url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/index2.html"},
      {"id":8447,"url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/index3.html"}
   ]
  }
}
```

With this modified JSON, you could output:

```
console.log(modifiedJson.result.results.length);
```